# Eclipse's Editor occasionally inserts a single space when I hit tab instead of the configured two spaces. How to prevent this?

Tags: eclipse, editor

I have the Eclipse Editor configured to use two spaces instead of tabs. However, it sometimes randomly only adds a single space when I press tab. This seems to occur only on existing lines e.g. if I create a new white line and hit tab, I'll never get the single space. The only spot where I've seen tab consistently produce a single space is after a closing bracket `}`. Is there a way to prevent these single space tabs?

Comment: Type one character on a new line and press Tab.  You should get the single space.  The Tab spaces to an even column number.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Indeed that is happening. How can I configure it to always insert two spaces?

Comment: You can't.  Tabs are set on column numbers.  You can press the space bar twice when you're not at the start of a new line.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc If you would like to make this the answer I will accept it. It seems like a bizarre rule that limits the purpose of using tab to input two spaces. Why was it designed this way?